# MobileSim and gmapping

Tags: navigation, odometry, aria, laserscanner, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with MoblieSim and I have tow nodes: teleop_node and movement_node. The first one is running in my laptop and the second one in the p3dx.

I get the laser buffer readings and I build LaserScanner messages. I publish them in /base_scan in order to send them to the gmapping node (which must be running in another console, is it right?).

I guess gmapping also needs odometry. How can I know it? Is it just the cmd_vel used to teleoperate the robot?

Thanks beforehand

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42342/mobilesim-and-gmapping/) by [Julio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1458/julio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, you might want to check if gmapping expects scans on /base_scan. I think it might be /scan, then you'll need to remap that.

Second: No, cmd_vel is not odometry. Odometry is the robot's pose in the odom frame. It is usually send via tf for gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1458/julio/) on 2012-08-27**:
Thank you for your answer.

First: you are right, it's the /scan topic. Thanks ;-)

Second: how can I get the robot's pose from mobilesim? If not, how to run the movement node in the stage simulator given by ros (and get the odometry and publish it to gmapping)?

Thanks again